# Convert mp3 audio string to .mp3 audio file in iOS

Tags: ios

I got base64 string of .mp3 from server

```
   NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:[dictResult      
     objectForKey:@"voiceString"] options:0];
```

here I got Audio Data object audioData(30571bytes).

using following code I am trying to save nsdata object to .mp3 file in temp directory.

```
  NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory()  
     stringByAppendingString:objAddXpnseconfigFromRcnt.bAudioName]];

  [audioData writeToFile:[audioFileURL absoluteString] atomically:YES];
```

but the above code is not working?

the method **writeToFile:atomically:** doesn't create audio file in temp directory.

Comment: Did you check what `[audioFileURL absoluteString]` gives back? It should be something like this: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E2496D46-A7AA-453A-899E-0ABCFC5E818B/tmp/yourfile.mp3`

Comment: I am trying it on simulator. it gives me actual path of tmp directory

Comment: @user623396 sorry I think I didn't get actual path result is file:///Users/vinodjadhav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/067A2EAC-9987-4861-8746-97117DCE72F2/data/Containers/Data/Application/08604164-3948-4609-BC8F-6A3655AFE8DA/tmp/1417092656_2_mobile_voice.mp3

Comment: thanks for quick reply I got issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the path you are creating:

```
[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:objAddXpnseconfigFromRcnt.bAudioName]
```

Should of course be

```
[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:objAddXpnseconfigFromRcnt.bAudioName]
```

As you can see I use the `stringByAppendingPathComponentL:` which will correctly append the filename.

And Why are are creating a `NSURL` for the file path only to convert it back to path?

---

Also it is good practice to not write everything in one line and always make use of the methods with have an `error:` parameter. This wil make debugging easier, the following code is the same but way easier to debug:

```
NSString *tempPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *fileName = [tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:objAddXpnseconfigFromRcnt.bAudioName];
NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![audioData writeToURL:audioFileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error] {
    NSLog(@"Failed to write MP3 data: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: .. for not writing all the code in a single line. You can see who is used to debugging their code and who is not. Set a breakpoint on the tempPath line. Step over it. Check what's tempPath. Step over the next line. Check whats in fileName. Step over next line. Check what's in audioFileURL.